# using c# in unity3D to open a window once the user clicked on a specific object

Tags: c#, onclick, window, unity-game-engine

I want to write a code in unity3d using c# that whenever the user clicked on a object inside the game a window will appears contain a brief information (that was retrieved from the database) about this object? can you please help me? i'm a beginner =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, add this script to the gameobject you will click

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OnClick : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    private bool PopUp;
    public string Info;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        PopUp = true;
    }

    void DrawInfo()
    {
        Rect rect = new Rect (20,20, 300, 200);
        Rect close = new Rect (300,20,20,20);
        if (PopUp)
        {
            GUI.Box(rect, Info);
            if (GUI.Button(close,"X"))
            {
                PopUp = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        DrawInfo();
    }
}
```

This code should help you start.